# AwStats IIS Custom fields don't parse

Tags: iis, awstats

My AwStats 7.8 doesn't update when I add custom fields to my IIS log:

crypt-protocol crypt-cipher crypt-hash crypt-keyexchange

I've added these fields to my LogFormat =

```
LogFormat = "all the other fields + crypt-protocol crypt-cipher crypt-hash crypt-keyexchange"
```

I get the error:
Your log file logresolvemerge.pl D:/Data/log/u_ex*.log | must have a bad format or LogFormat parameter setup does not match this format.

Comment: I suspect this is because there is a problem with your LogFormat, you can try to use the LogFormat in the link: https://serverfault.com/questions/723584/awstats-cant-parse-my-log

Comment: I have a feeling these column names are not recognized. I added them to the LogFormat as usual. The links seems to be for nginx.

Comment: This is an explanation about AWStats LogFormat: https://www.internetofficer.com/awstats/log-format/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer: these extra fields are not recognized by AwStats. You have to rename the extra LogFormat columns to: **other**.

So you get this:

```
LogFormat = "all the other fields + other other other other"
```